# Iteratively read a fixed number of lines into R

Tags: json, r

I have a josn file I'm working with that contains multiple json objects in a single file. R is unable to read the file as a whole. But since each object occurs at regular intervals, I would like to iteratively read a fixed number of lines into R.

There are a number of SO questions on reading single lines into R but I have been unable to extend these solutions to a fixed number of lines. For my problem I need to read 16 lines into R at a time (eg 1-16, 17-32 etc)

I have tried using a loop but can't seem to get the syntax right:

```
## File
file <- "results.json"

## Create connection
con <- file(description=file, open="r")

## Loop over a file connection
for(i in 1:1000) {
  tmp <- scan(file=con, nlines=16, quiet=TRUE)
  data[i] <- fromJSON(tmp)
}
```

The file contains over 1000 objects of this form:

```
{
  "object": [
    [
      "a",
      0
    ],
    [
      "b",
      2
    ],
    [
      "c",
      2
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: have you tried `jsonlite::stream_in`?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

*EDITED* to make it use a list and Reduce into one file

```
## Loop over a file connection
data <- NULL
for(i in 1:1000) {
  tmp <- scan(file=con, nlines=16, skip=(i-1)*16, quiet=TRUE)
  data[[i]] <- fromJSON(tmp)
}
df <- Reduce(function(x, y) {paste(x, y, collapse = " ")})
```

You would have to make sure that you don't reach further than the end of the file though ;-)

Comment: This gets me close but it creates a tmp object that is a character vector [1:21].  With `paste(scan(file=con, what="character", sep=" ", nlines=16, skip=(i-1)*16, quiet=TRUE),collapse=" ")` I can convert it to a single character string but then jsonlite doesn't recognize it because scan() strips the quotes from "object"

Answer (score 0):

With @tomtom inspiration I was able to find a solution.

```
## File
file <- "results.json"
## Loop over a file 
for(i in 1:1000) {
  tmp <- paste(scan(file=file, what="character", sep="\n", nlines=16, skip=(i-1)*16, quiet=TRUE),collapse=" ")
  assign(x = paste("data", i, sep = "_"), value = fromJSON(tmp))
}
```

I couldn't create a connection as each time I tried the connection would close before the file had been completely read. So I got rid of that step.

I had to include the `what="character"` variable as scan() seems to expect a number by default.

I included `sep="\n"`, paste() and `collapse=" "` to create a single string rather than the vector of characters that scan() creates by default.

Finally I just changed the final assignment operator to have a bit more control over the names of the output.